# Youtube Video is not loaded in WebView

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I want to display a list of Youtube Video using ListView and WebView. But Videos are not loaded.

WebView always shows **An Error Occured** as the picture below:
[image]

Currently I don't know how to bind URL directly to **WebView** in AXML file, therefor I customized a **BindableWebView** instead:

```
public class BindableWebView : WebView
    {

        public BindableWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        private string _webViewContent;

        public string WebViewContent
        {
            get { return _webViewContent; }
            set
            {
                _webViewContent = value;
                LoadHtmlString();
            }
        }

        private void LoadHtmlString()
        {
            LoadData(WebViewContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
    }
```

This is Layout AXML file:

```
    <dc.AlphaLinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="Click ItemClickCommand">

        <!--Video Thumbnail-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/ProductImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ProductImageHeight"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/ExtraNewsImagePadding">
            <BindableWebView
            android:id="@+id/playerWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxBind="WebViewContent Video.YoutubeUrl" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
           .....
        </LinearLayout>

</dc.AlphaLinearLayout>
```

This is Video Model:

```
namespace ....Shared.Models
{
    public class Video
    {
        public string YoutubeId { get; set; }

        public string YoutubeImageUrl => $"https://img.youtube.com/vi/{YoutubeId}/0.jpg";

        public string YoutubeUrl => $"<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{YoutubeId}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

        public Guid NewsId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And **VideoListViewm** in C#:

```
namespace DeHeus.Droid.Views
{
    public class VideoListView : DetailViewWithShare
    {
        protected override int LayoutId => Resource.Layout.VideoListView;
        private CustomMvxListView _videoListview;

        protected override void InitView(View view)
        {
            _videoListview = view.FindViewById<CustomMvxListView>(Resource.Id.videoList);
            _videoListview.ItemTemplateId = Resource.Layout.VideoListItemView;
        }

        protected override void CreateBinding()
        {
            var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<VideoListView, VideoListViewModel>();

            bindingSet.Bind(_videoListview.Adapter)
                .For(v => v.ItemsSource)
                .To(vm => vm.VideoItemViewModels);


            bindingSet.Bind(_videoListview)
                .For(v => v.ScrollToBottom)
                .To(vm => vm.ScrollToBottomCommand);

            bindingSet.Apply();
        }
    }
}
```

Running debug, the WebViewContent gets exact Url but I don't know why it doesn't work as I thought: `"<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/usoFYAqOMyA\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"`
[image]
Does anyone has idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a webview and not directly integrating youtube in your app? (Curious)

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, Youtube Player requires users to install Youtube App on their phone first. I want to allow users to play video with or without youtube on their devices @G.hakim

Comment: I do not think it is mandatory to have the youtube app in your device, for a simple understanding you can check [this java example](http://www.androhub.com/how-to-show-youtube-video-thumbnail-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Comment: @G.hakim I'm using YoutubePlayer now and facing this issue, could you take a look and give me some advice ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778288/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-youtube-player-youtubeplayerview-in-lis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done a lot of researching and I have finally solved the issue.

All you need is putting `SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` before LoadData

```
 public BindableWebView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
            WebSettings settings = this.Settings;
            settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        }

        private string _webViewContent;

        public string WebViewContent
        {
            get { return _webViewContent; }
            set
            {
                _webViewContent = value;
                LoadHtmlString();
            }
        }

        private void LoadHtmlString()
        {
            LoadData(WebViewContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
```